# WCF: show all the config params of a channel at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to remove [WcfContrib](https://wcfcontrib.codeplex.com/) from a WCF service.
In a nutshell, it is a library to "max out" all the parameters of a WCF channel (timeouts, message size, etc...).

Now, to ensure I don't break the service, I need to be 100% sure that after I remove WcfContrib I keep all the current parameters maximized.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to log/display on a page the "runtime values" of a channel.

I am also open to alternative solutions/suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be specific about what these "run time values" are?

Comment: The information I am looking for is: any parameter about the channel (max message size, max timeouts, max number of connections, ... ... ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen that kind of tool before. But I have an idea about this.

You can develop a WCF endpoint behavior extension for this. This endpoint behavior can get these values that you are interested and log to somewhere.

This way you don't have to change your service code or something. You will just add this endpoint behavior to web.config of your application.

Comment: Thanks, what I need to know is where exactly this behavior is going to take the information.

The information I am looking for is: any parameter about the channel (max message size, max timeouts, max number of connections, ... ... ...)

Comment: You can access many Channel properties in an endpoint behavior. http://www.alltechnicalfaqs.com/2010/08/servicethrottlingbehavior-in-wcf.html this site can give you an idea. You can access ChannelDispatcher in an endpoint behavior.